# How do I buy a flagship?

Tags: anno-1404

I've just started the game, and I've searched Google and I can't seem to find the quest anywhere.

How do I buy the flag ship from Lord Richard Northburough? I think my game might be glitched.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once Lord Richard Northburgh offers you the ship you will be able to buy it.
This usually happens when you unlock the attainment `Imperial Merchant Fleet (Rank 1)`. You can find a fulll explanation of [attainments here](http://anno1404.wikia.com/wiki/Attainments).

Once you have unlocked the attainment using honor Lord Northburgh will prompt you to buy a ship. Go to his warehouse on his Island. Make sure that you do not click on the warehouse or any of the buildings. If you have left click any where in the ocean. Make sure that Lord Northburgh portrait is no longer in the upper right hand corner of the screen.

Click on the ship directly in front of the harbor, Lord Northburgh portrait will popup in the right asking if you want to buy the ship for a small amount of coins. Usually between 3k - 5k in coins.

Accept this offer and you will have your first flag ship. It will usually be called the "Santa Barbra" or at least it was in my case.